# Не удаётся установить windows 7 после установки ubuntu

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu

Когда я захожу в установку windows 7 там вылезает только картинка и мышка. А сама установка не включается. Кто знает как это исправить помогите.

Comment: Установку запускали правильно ([пример][1]) ?    [1]: http://notebookclub.org/article/windows/5-windows-7-install.html

Answer (score 3):

Неверный порядок установки ОС:
 1. ставим windows;
 2. ставим Linux.
Наоборот не получится. Все дело в том, что винда затрет загрузчик линукс (вот такая она нахальная - других систем не терпит) и Linux перестанет грузиться.
Вот что нам дает Гугл: linux и windows  на одном компьюторе...
.
Загрузку производите с DVD диска или из-под ОС?

Comment: можно ставить в любом порядке. Единственное, что если кто то затрет загрузчик, то его нужно будет восстановить. Если загрузчик груб (классика для линукса), то просто любым лайв CD загружаемся и восстанавливаем загрузчик.

Comment: Нет смысла производить лишние телодвижения и напрягать мозг, если сразу все можно сделать как положено!